# How to desearilaize the json which contains list of entity as well as other properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a json comprising list of MyFacebookClass and when i am deserializing the list of MyFacebookClass then i am getting the error that no blank constructor defined for CustomObject though i have already defined constructor as shown below,so please help me out.

```
    public class MyFacebookClass
    {
    public MyFacebookClass
    {
      data =new List<CustomObject>();
    }
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public int Id{get;set;}
        public List<CustomObject> data {get;set;}
    }

    public class CustomObject 
    {
    public CustomObject()
    {
    }
      public string id {get;set;}
      public string name {get;set;}
    }
```

I am using:

```
    List<MyFacebookClass> routes_list = new List<MyFacebookClass>();
    JavaScriptSerializer jSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    routes_list = jSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyFacebookClass>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have no constructor for `CustomObject` in the code that you have posted. basically, a constructor is a method that has no return type and is the same name as the declaring class.  You DO have a constructor for your `MyFacebookClass`  [here is the MSDN documentation on constructors.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)

```
public class CustomObject 
{
  public CustomObject()
  {
    /*  now you have a constructor */
  }
  public string id {get;set;}
  public string name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: No, I have already created constructor for both. That was missing part in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Working perfectly fine. Only issue I found in your code was, MyFacebookClass class constructor should have brackets

```
public class MyFacebookClass
{
    public MyFacebookClass()
    {
        data = new List<CustomObject>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<CustomObject> data { get; set; }
}

public class CustomObject
{
    public CustomObject()
    {
        /*  now you have a constructor */
    }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public List<MyFacebookClass> Deserialize(string json)
    {
        List<MyFacebookClass> routes_list = new List<MyFacebookClass>();
        JavaScriptSerializer jSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return jSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyFacebookClass>>(json); 
    }
}
```

[TestMethod()]

```
    public void doSomethingTest()
    {
        Main target = new Main(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        Assert.AreEqual(target.Deserialize(""), null);
    }
```